# Island Perimeter- Getting time limit excedded - python

Tags: python-3.x, graph, breadth-first-search

**Question**

You are given row x col grid representing a map where grid[i][j] = 1 represents land and grid[i][j] = 0 represents water.

Grid cells are connected horizontally/vertically (not diagonally). The grid is completely surrounded by water, and there is exactly one island (i.e., one or more connected land cells).

The island doesn't have "lakes", meaning the water inside isn't connected to the water around the island. One cell is a square with side length 1. The grid is rectangular, width and height don't exceed 100. Determine the perimeter of the island.

Example 1:

Input: grid = [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0]]
Output: 16
Explanation: The perimeter is the 16 yellow stripes in the image above.[image]

**My code**:

islandPerimeter() is the solution function

```
def islandPerimeter(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    v=[[0,0]]
    q=[[0,0]]
    c=0
    return self.bfs(grid,v,q,c)

def bfs(self,grid,v,q,c):
    if q==[]:
        return c
    i=q[0][0]
    j=q[0][1]
    if grid[i][j]:
        c+=4
    if i-1 > -1:
        if [i-1,j] not in v:
            q.append([i-1,j])
            v.append([i-1,j])
        if grid[i-1][j] and grid[i][j]:
            c-=1
    if j-1 > -1:
        if [i,j-1] not in v:
            q.append([i,j-1])
            v.append([i,j-1])
        if grid[i][j-1] and grid[i][j]:
            c-=1
    try:
        a=grid[i+1][j]
        if [i+1,j] not in v:
            q.append([i+1,j])
            v.append([i+1,j])
        if grid[i+1][j] and grid[i][j]:
            c-=1
    except:
        pass
    try:
        a=grid[i][j+1]
        if [i,j+1] not in v:
            q.append([i,j+1])
            v.append([i,j+1])
        if grid[i][j+1] and grid[i][j]:
            c-=1
    except:
        pass
    del q[0]


    return self.bfs(grid,v,q,c)
```

q=queue for bfs

v=visited array

i=row

j=column

c=final answer

I have started from (0,0) cell and traversed the graph using bfs. For every island cell I have increased the count by 4 and for every island cell if the adjacent cell is an island cell then for every such island cell I have reduced the count by 1.
But I am getting **time limit exceeded error**.

Comment: Are you able to verify that you're not infinitely recursing?

Comment: yes, time limit is excedding on 5814 th testcase.

Answer (score 0):

there is exactly one island

==>

every land cell is connected to every opther land cell

So you can simplify your algorithm

- Search cells in order e.g. top left  column by column row by row to bottom right - stop when first land cell found.
- Search neighbors for land cells back tracking when water cell - recording all land cells found